# Sybase ASE 15.7 SQL recursive query

Tags: sql, recursion, sybase

just wanted to know is recursive search removed from Sybase since version 12? If so, how to handle recursive search incase needed?

For example: Table 'sequence' as below

```
item |  next_item
------------------
5    |  null
2    |  3
3    |  4
1    |  2
4    |  5
```

how can I get the result like below

```
1    
2
3
4
5
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too vague. Which Sybase product (IQ, ASE, Anywhere), what kind of recursive search - SQL?

Comment: Thanks for reminding, Rich, it's a Sybase ASE 15.7

Comment: Ok so do you want one result with the next_item value in a single comma delimited string or do you want the results for the five rows as separate results?

Comment: Hi Rich, i just edited the question, just get the result set of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} is fine. No need to be comma delimited string. Thanks

Comment: I dont see how thats recursive though all you're asking for it would appear is 'select item from sequence order by item' - if not you need to explain what exactly you need for result because 'result' isnt a column in your data.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I updated the table, the data in column 'next_item' is the successor of data in column 'item'. The query result should be the full sequence. I remove the 'result' for less confusion.